# jquery.POST to MVC controller to return JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I have created a following model

```
public class myModel
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int[] days;
}
```

Then I created an action in a controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myCtrlAction(myModel thisModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(thisModel);
        }
        else
        {
            string errorMessage = "<div class=\"validation-summary-errors\">"
              + "The following errors occurred:<ul>";
            foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
            {
                var error = ModelState[key].Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                if (error != null)
                {
                    errorMessage += "<li class=\"field-validation-error\">"
                     + error.ErrorMessage + "</li>";
                }
            }
            errorMessage += "</ul>";
            return Json(new myModel { Name = errorMessage });  //just for now
        } 
   }
```

In my javascript I send the data using jQuery.post() as

```
$("#myBtn").click(function () {
var mydata = {
          ID: $("#inputID").val(),
          Name: $("#inputName").val(),
          Days: $("#selectDays").select2("val")
       }
    var url = 'myController/myCtrlAction';  //definitly it was writtern as @Url.Action
    $.post(url, mydata, function(data) { alert(data); //which shows [object object] 
                     }, 'json');
 });
```

Now On request when I debug in Chrome I saw in headers as

**Form Data**
ID: 5
Name: SomeName
Days[]: 6
Days[]: 5

In Response I got json format of my model as

***{ID: "0", Name: "null", Days: "null"}*** it means my model state is valid but why its not having the values?

Any body has any idea.  what I did wrong or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your model's data is not set thus you get null values on Chrome.

If your javascript does not have a typo (and that you only made a typo when creating the question, then try this in your method `myCtrlAction`;

First try create getters and setters for your fields in myModel. Then;

replace;

```
 errorMessage += "</ul>";

 return Json(new myModel { Name = errorMessage });  //just for now
```

with this;

```
 myModel myMODTest= new myModel();
 myMODTest.setID(1111);
 myMODTest.setName("testName");
 myMODTest.setDays({1,2,3});
 return Json(myMODTest);  //just for now
```

See if you get on your browser the following;

`{ID: "1111", Name: "testName", Days: "{1,2,3}"}`

Comment: let me see, yep I missed get set Awwww come on. How it can be. Thanks mwangi.

Comment: Thanks. lolz at my self. It should not be the question but you got the vote. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, can you tell me why I have not receive array in my model even I put getter setter for array int[] Days. In Chrome Developer tools arrays are display as Days[]: 6 and Days[]: 5. In response I have Days from my model as NULL. I changed it to List<int> Days in my model it still returning null in Response.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how it shows on Chrome Developer tools when you have int[] for days?

Comment: I got it I have to write, traditional: true in jquery ajax. Thanks. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I do this following:

- 1: JavaScript: When clicking the button: Serialize the form-data and send it to the Controller:

  ```
  function ajaxSubmitEditSupplierQuote() {
      var formData = $("#SupplierQuoteEditForm").serializeArray();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "SupplierQuote")',
          data: formData,
          dataType: "json",
          cache: false,
          success: function (data1) {
              // Here I create then a new Url-string.   
              // Simple access your Json Data, as you have named it in the return of the Controller-Action.
              var strUrl = "/Equipment/" + data1.target.toString();                   
              // ...
              // 
              // ...
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- 2: Controller-Action with custom Json return

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(SupplierQuoteDto supplierQuoteDto)
  {

      // ........... code

      if (_userContext.EquipmentAction.ClickedAction == ActionType.Create)
          return Json(new { target = "Create" });
      else if (_userContext.EquipmentAction.ClickedAction == ActionType.Edit)
          return Json(new { target = "Edit" });
      else
          return new EmptyResult();
  }
  ```
- 3: Alternatively if you want to catch also the EmptyResult() then in the JavaScript, check simply in the

  ```
  success: function (data1) { 
      if (data1.toString() == "") {
          // .... alert
      }
      else {
          /// .... go on with coding
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

check your javascript code where you do the post. You have a typo: '.' instead of ',':

```
$.post(url, mydata, function(data) { alert(data); }, 'json');
```

Comment: Thanks. Typo fixed, but my concern is why I cannot see in Developer tools (Chrome), the values I sent to the CtrlAction of myController when json retuned.